# How does Salman Khan make his screencasts?

Tags: software, screen-casting, tutorial

Just wondering what software he uses. I see his videos regularly and I'm somewhat impressed by the video and audio quality of his screen-casts.

Comment: Could you link to one or two of them?

Comment: This is probably in reference to the [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/). Here's a [video example](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/solving-linear-equations/v/variables-and-expressions-1).

Answer (score 1):

He uses Camtasia Pro ($200) a Wacom tablet and (at least on the earliest videos) MS Paint. And a head mic.

http://www.teachthought.com/technology/how-to-screencast-like-the-khan-academy/

On a mac, a similar piece of screen capture software would be Screenflow, although Khan works on a Windows machine:

http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/